# how to print graphical layout in vb6?

Tags: printing, vb6

How can i print mix text and graphics using vb6?..,

i want the output to have an image at the top and some graphical background in the in the whole printing output.

tnx for the replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB6 will allow you to do just that in many ways. Here is one:

Create a new form, add an Image onto the form, and add a label on top of the image, and set the label kind as transparent for the background color to let the image be seen.

do whatever you want with the font size and location of the label, and when you are happy with what you got, let VB execute this instruction ():

```
Sub btnPrint_Click()

    Me.PrintForm   'This will print to the default printer with no questions asked
                   'so you better make sure printing is possible before you reach here

End Sub
```